# form_tag namespace option not working for html ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in each table row and want to prefix each input element id in each form. The following doesn't work, the input element id's aren't being prefixed.

```
      <%= form_tag non_model_path, namespace: "obj_#{obj.id}",
                                   remote: true do %>
```

Also where should I look for official documentation of the form_tag options? I could only find the input element methods documented.

Comment: Here's a link to the official Rails 5.1 `form_tag` docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it's only available to form_for. No mention of a namespace option in form_tag

Comment: Do you want to set the `id`'s attributes of each form @rigyt?

Comment: I think you'd need to set the `id` on each input element manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`namespace` is not available as an option to `form_tag` unfortunately (only with `form_for`). To achieve the same result each individual element in the form must have its `id` explicitly prefixed.

ps - if I'm given a reason for the downvote I would be happy to improve the question if it is lacking something?